# How to scrape a table with degree symbol in R and Python?

Tags: python, r

I am trying to scrape the table in this [website](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Polygon)

First, I tried the `R` from [here](http://rafalab.dfci.harvard.edu/dsbook/web-scraping.html) with code as follows:

```
url <- paste0("https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Polygon")
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
h <- read_html(url)
class(h)
tab <- h |> html_nodes("table")
tab[[1]]
tab <- tab[[1]] |> html_table()
class(tab)
tab
```

The last two columns with `$\circ$` are missing; the same problem happened when I tried `Python` with code from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/scraping-table-data-from-websites-using-a-single-line-in-python-ba898d54e2bc):

```
import pandas as pd
URL = "https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Polygon"
#tables = pd.read_html(URL,match="Number of Sides")
tables=pd.read_html(URL,attrs = {'class' : 'wikitable'})
print(tables)
print("There are : ",len(tables)," tables")
print("Take look at table 0")
tables[0]
```

I wonder if you could help me fix the problem, or suggest a new way to scrape the whole table from the link. thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the two approaches?

Comment: The degree cells are images where the text is stored in the alt attributes.  `tab |> html_nodes("img") |> html_attr("alt")`

Comment: @cheersmate: the problem is that last two columns with $\circ$ are missing.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: it worked but the results are like $180^\\circ$; I wonder if you could change it into $180^\circ$: change the \\  into \ ? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. The degrees are in image elements so you must extract their "alt"  attributes.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(rvest)
})

link <- "https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Polygon"
page <- read_html(link)

df1 <- page %>%
  html_element('table.wikitable') %>%
  html_table()

angles <- page %>%
  html_element('table.wikitable') %>%
  html_elements('img.latex') %>%
  html_attr('alt') %>%
  gsub("[^[:digit:]]+", "", .) %>%
  as.integer() %>%
  matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

df1[2:3] <- angles
df1
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   `Number of Sides` `Sum of Interior angles` Individual angle measure in regul…¹
#>               <int>                    <int>                               <int>
#> 1                 3                      180                                  60
#> 2                 4                      360                                  90
#> 3                 5                      540                                 108
#> 4                 6                      720                                 120
#> 5                 8                     1080                                 135
#> # … with abbreviated variable name
#> #   ¹​`Individual angle measure in regular polygon`
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

To keep the latex code, remove the `gsub` editing and the coercion to integer. The code to create `df1` and the beginning of the `angles` pipe are the same.

```r
angles <- page %>%
  html_element('table.wikitable') %>%
  html_elements('img.latex') %>%
  html_attr('alt') %>%
  matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

df1[2:3] <- angles
df1
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   `Number of Sides` `Sum of Interior angles` Individual angle measure in regul…¹
#>               <int> <chr>                    <chr>                              
#> 1                 3 "$180^\\circ$"           "$60^\\circ$"                      
#> 2                 4 "$360^\\circ$"           "$90^\\circ$"                      
#> 3                 5 "$540^\\circ$"           "$108^\\circ$"                     
#> 4                 6 "$720^\\circ$"           "$120^\\circ$"                     
#> 5                 8 "$1080^\\circ$"          "$135^\\circ$"                     
#> # … with abbreviated variable name
#> #   ¹​`Individual angle measure in regular polygon`
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks for your help. It worked but I wonder what if we want to include the degree symbol ($\circ$ ) for the numbers in the table?

Comment: if I do not use `gsub("[^[:digit:]]+", "", .) %>%  as.integer() %>%`, the results are like $180^\\circ$; I wonder if you could change it into $180^\circ$: change the  \\ into  \? thanks!

Comment: @Pai That result is just one ```\```, the other one is an artifact of R's print function. It is there in order not to escape the second, the real one.

Comment: OK, I see. but when I use `xtable(df1, type = "latex")` to export it as a `latex` table, it gets very messy like this-`\$180\verb|^|$\backslash$circ\$` it would be much better to get `$180^\circ$`, which could be directly editable in `Latex`. I wonder if you could do it. thanks!

Comment: @Pai I have now edited and it seems to be the result you want. Don't worry about the double ```\\```, what I said above still applies.

Comment: You're right. But I wonder how you could export `df1` out of `R`? I used  `xtable(df1, type = "latex") ` to export it as a `Latex` table, it gets very messy like this-`\$180\verb|^|$\backslash$circ\$`. Interestingly, it is `$180^\circ$` in `PDF` generated from `Latex`.

Comment: @Pai If if the following works `kb <- knitr::kable(df1, "latex");Hmisc::latex(kb)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250722/discussion-between-pai-and-rui-barradas).